# Procedure SP_BGTable has no parameters and arguments were supplied

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

This is my stored procedure :

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[Insert_BranchRegistration]
@branchname varchar(100),
@address nvarchar(200),
@phone bigint,
@email varchar(200),
@bloodgroup int,
@nobags int
as
INSERT INTO [dbo].[BranchRegistration]
           ([branchname]
           ,[address]
           ,[phone]
           ,[email]
           ,[bloodgroup]
           ,[nobags])
     VALUES
           (@branchname
           ,@address
           ,@phone
           ,@email
           ,@bloodgroup
           ,@nobags)
  GO 
     ALTER procedure [dbo].[SP_BGTable] as SELECT [bgid] ,[name] FROM [dbo].[BGTable]
```

This is my asp.net html code.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="BranchRegi.aspx.cs" Inherits="BloodBank.BranchRegi" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
      <div class="pagecontent">
        <div class="addform">
            <asp:Button ID="BtnAdd" runat="server" CssClass="button" Text="Add" />
            <br />
              <asp:Label ID="ErrorMessage" ForeColor="Red" class="label_inv" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
            <br />
        </div>
        <div class="form">
            <div class="border-line">

                <div>
                  <span class="width">  <asp:Label ID="lblBranchName" class="label_inv" runat="server" Text="Branch Name"></asp:Label></span>
                    <span class="leftmargin">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtBranchName" class="textbox_body" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RfvBranchName" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Please enter branch name." ControlToValidate="txtBranchName"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rxvBranchName" runat="server"
                            ControlToValidate="txtBranchName" ErrorMessage="Only alphabets are allowed"
                            ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="[a-zA-Z]+"> </asp:RegularExpressionValidator></span>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div>

                  <span class="width"> <asp:Label ID="lblAddress" class="label_inv" runat="server" Text="Address"></asp:Label></span>
                  <span style="margin-left:95px"> <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" Style="height: 70px" class="textbox_body" runat="server" TextMode="multiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                   <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RfvAddress" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter Address." ControlToValidate="txtAddress"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                   <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rxvAddress" runat="server"
                        ControlToValidate="txtAddress" ErrorMessage="Only alphabets are allowed"
                        ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="[a-zA-Z]+" > </asp:RegularExpressionValidator></span>
                 </div>
                <br />
                <div>
                     <span class="width"> <asp:Label ID="lblPhoneNumber" class="label_inv" runat="server" Text="Phone Number"></asp:Label></span>
                     <span class="leftmargin" style="margin-left:50px"> <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhonenumber" class="textbox_body" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RfvPhonenumber" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter phone number." ControlToValidate="txtPhonenumber"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>                 
                     <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 
                     ControlToValidate="txtPhonenumber" ErrorMessage="Please enter valid mobile number" 
                        ValidationExpression="[0-9]{10}"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator></span>
                   </div>
                <br />
                <div>

                     <span class="width"> <asp:Label ID="lblEmailID" class="label_inv" runat="server" Text="Email ID"></asp:Label></span>
                     <span class="leftmargin" style="margin-left:85px" ><asp:TextBox ID="txtEmailID" class="textbox_body" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvEmailID" ForeColor="Red"  runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter email." ControlToValidate="txtEmailID"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                     <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" 
                runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Enter Valid Email ID"
                    ValidationGroup="vgSubmit" ControlToValidate="txtEmailID" 
                    CssClass="requiredFieldValidateStyle"
                    ForeColor="Red" 
                    ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*">
                    </asp:RegularExpressionValidator></span>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div>
                    <span class="width"><asp:Label ID="lblGroup" class="label_inv" runat="server" Text="Blood Group"></asp:Label></span>
                    <span class="leftmargin"> 
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlBlood" runat="server">
                         </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvBloodGroup" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter valid group name." ControlToValidate="ddlBlood"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                     </span>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div>
                    <span class="width"> <asp:Label ID="lblNoBags" class="label_inv" runat="server" Text="No. of Bags"></asp:Label></span>
                    <span class="leftmargin"><asp:TextBox ID="txtNoBags" Style="margin-left: 5px" class="textbox_body" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvNoBags" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter branch name." ControlToValidate="txtNoBags"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="RegularExpressionValidator4"
                   ControlToValidate="txtNoBags"
                   ValidationExpression="\d+"
                   Display="Static"
                   EnableClientScript="true"
                   ErrorMessage="Please enter numbers only"
                   runat="server"/></span>

                </div>
                <br />
                <div>
                     <span class="width" style="margin-left:200px" ><asp:Button ID="invSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="invSubmit_Click" /></span>

                   <span style="margin-left:50px" >  <asp:Button ID="invReset" runat="server" Text="Reset" /></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    <link href="Content/site1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style>
        .leftmargin 
        {
            margin-left:60px;
        }
        .width 
        {
            width:200px;
        }

    </style>
</asp:Content>
```

and server side C# code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using BloodBank.Controllers;
using BloodBank.Models;

namespace BloodBank
{
    public partial class BranchRegi : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        #region VARIABLES
        DataSet ds = null;
        BranchRegistration objBranch;
        Operation objOperation;
        #endregion
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                filldrop();
                ddlBlood.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }

        }
        public void filldrop()
        {
            ds = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(Common.GetConnectionString(), CommandType.StoredProcedure, CommanName.StoredProcedures.Select_Group);
            ddlBlood.DataSource = ds;
            ddlBlood.DataTextField = "name";
            ddlBlood.DataValueField = "bgid";
            ddlBlood.DataBind();

            ddlBlood.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select", "0"));
        }

        protected void invSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            objBranch = new BranchRegistration();
            objOperation = new Operation();
            try
            {
                objBranch.branchname = txtBranchName.Text.Trim();
                objBranch.address = txtAddress.Text.Trim();
                objBranch.phone = Int64.Parse(txtPhonenumber.Text.Trim());
                objBranch.email = txtEmailID.Text.Trim();

                //Response.Write(ddlBlood.SelectedValue.ToString());

                objBranch.bloodgroup = int.Parse(ddlBlood.SelectedItem.Value);
                objBranch.nobags = int.Parse(txtNoBags.Text.Trim());
                objOperation.RegisterBranch(objBranch);
                ErrorMessage.Text = CommanName.Messages.registerSuccess;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                ErrorMessage.Text = CommanName.Messages.registerUnsuccess;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
int iResult = SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(Common.GetConnectionString(), CommandType.StoredProcedure,CommanName.StoredProcedures.Select_Group, new SqlParameter("@branchname", objBranch.branchname), new SqlParameter("@address", objBranch.address), new SqlParameter("@phone", objBranch.phone), new SqlParameter("@email", objBranch.email), new SqlParameter("@bloodgroup", objBranch.bloodgroup), new SqlParameter("@nobags", objBranch.nobags));
```

The exception is:

> Procedure SP_BGTable has no parameters and arguments were supplied.

Comment: This sp for autoupdated  dropdown .....please  help..........................USE [BloodBank]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SP_BGTable]    Script Date: 5/18/2015 2:23:12 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[SP_BGTable]
 
as
SELECT [bgid]
      ,[name]
  FROM [dbo].[BGTable]

Comment: following error occurs through exception....Procedure SP_BGTable has no parameters and arguments were supplied.

Comment: RegisterBranch is method for ExecuteNon

Comment: int iResult = SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(Common.GetConnectionString(), CommandType.StoredProcedure,CommanName.StoredProcedures.Select_Group,
         new SqlParameter("@branchname", objBranch.branchname),
         new SqlParameter("@address", objBranch.address),
         new SqlParameter("@phone", objBranch.phone),
         new SqlParameter("@email", objBranch.email),
         new SqlParameter("@bloodgroup", objBranch.bloodgroup),
         new SqlParameter("@nobags", objBranch.nobags));

Comment: You're calling the wrong stored procedure, the exception is saying that `SP_BGTable` has no params, but the stored procedure you list is `[Insert_BranchRegistration]`?  In your comment above, `SP_BGTable` has no params, but it looks like you're passing some.

Comment: Fixed code formatting, tags...

Comment: Reedit your question and include all the relevant code and especially the code lines, where you get the exception (stack trace etc.) Do not include HTML code as it is not relevant here.

Answer (score 1):

ALTER procedure [dbo].[SP_BGTable] as SELECT [bgid] ,[name] FROM [dbo].[BGTable]

This is store procedure **SP_BGTable**. and there is no parameters! But you try to pass parameter in code.

I think you calling the wrong procedure. Change it to **Insert_BranchRegistration**